# How to deal with mathematical constants in templated code

Tags: c++, templates

I have a code (for which performance is crucial) that I can compile in single and double precision. We use a lot of physical constants throughout the code that come out of a `namespace Constants`. What is the most elegant way of providing the constants in the preferred precision, as I cannot template a namespace?

```
namespace Constants
{
    const double meaning_of_life = 42.;
}

template<typename TF>
TF multiply_number(const TF a)
{
    return Constants::meaning_of_life*a;
}

int main()
{
    double a = multiply_number<double>(5.);
    // With the call below, a cast is done in multiply_number.
    float b = multiply_number<float>(6.);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just turn the namespace into a class templated on storage type `T`, and make all the constants `static constexpr T`.

Comment: Since C++14 you can use [variable templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) for this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the namespace a class and make all of your constants static members of the class.  This will work for any version of C++.

If you are okay with only using a certain version or newer then you can use [variable templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) from C++14.  That will allow you to declare the variable as a template then then use the template type from the function to type it like

```
namespace Constants
{
    template <typename T>
    const T meaning_of_life = T(42);
}

template<typename TF>
TF multiply_number(const TF a)
{
    return Constants::meaning_of_life<TF>*a;
}
```

Comment: And the `T(42)` is nothing more than a static cast?

Comment: @Chiel Yeah.  This is to silence warnings if the value would be truncated.  You don't have to have it if you want those warnings to surface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
namespace Constants
{
    template <typename TF> struct meaning_of_life
    {
       static constexpr TF value = 42.;
    };
}

template<typename TF>
TF multiply_number(const TF a)
{
    return Constants::meaning_of_life<TF>::value*a;
}
```

If the constants need to be different, you can specialize the class template.